# Bicycling apps for Android

Tags: bike-computer, software, android

I have an Android smartphone, with GPS, accelerometer, 3G internet connection, and other features that seem useful for bicycling. Are there any good bicycling apps on Android?

One app per answer please; feel free to answer multiple times.

Comment: For some reason, I can't seem to make this community wiki (or I'm just missing where the checkbox is); it probably should be.

Comment: When I look at the question page, I don't see the checkbox either. I believe you need to have a certain amount of rep points to create a wiki post because there is an assumption that new users don't know the difference. - Flagged for attention...

Comment: @Gary According to http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki only 10 rep is required to create wiki posts; I should have plenty.

Comment: I agree, but I can't see where it is on the question page either - I can mark responses as wiki.  Even if I try to edit my existing questions I don't see the checkbox either.

Comment: If you edit the original question, you'll see a box for CW there; you can't do it up front. (I would have sworn that used to be an option before.) There doesn't seem to be any way of making an entire *thread* CW unless you're a moderator.

Comment: @neilfein Nope, even when I try editing my question, I don't see a checkbox for CW (even for other questions of mine which are not CW yet). Perhaps we should report a bug on meta.so?

Comment: @neilfein Oh. Community wiki for questions has been disabled for everyone but moderators. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action

Comment: @Brian - Of note: [Apps for stationary cycling](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2912/1119)

Comment: This thread is making me want to get an Android.

Comment: @NeilFein: Lack of ANT+ support is still an issue.

Comment: Per [discussion on meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/711), I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 18):

[image: endomondo]

[Endomondo](http://www.endomondo.com/)!!!! *Free your endorphins* : )

I love this app!!! I have used it to track over 1,000 miles of cycling this year. The android app is just a small part of the entire service. With endomondo you get

- challenges with your friends
- live updating of your route
- global challenges
- personal bests summary
- teams
- more

[image: endomondo workout page]

With their great android app you get the ability to track

- duration with option of auto pause
- distance
- speed
- avg. speed
- calories
- heart rate
- average heart rate
- listen/control music
- view current position and track on map
- view previous workouts
- set goal and get mile by mile updates on progress

[image: endomondo android app]

I personally really enjoy being able to use my bluetooth heart rate monitor with this android app.

[image: zephyr bluetooth heart rate monitor]

http://www.zephyr-technology.com/9600.0112.html

All my workout info is then updated live to the endomondo website where I can later inspect my workout in detail. If you are looking for a service/app to track your rides/workouts you have got to give this one a go.

Comment: Looks awesome, I have always wondered if someone made a bluetooth hrm for just this reason.

Comment: It's great! it's amazing how long the battery stays charged on this thing. : )

Comment: Yes, I too have been Endomondo heavily. Its amazing, I esp. like its auto pause feature.

Comment: Can it also be used as a navigation device? i.e : have custom maps and show you your live location (on screen) on the map?

Comment: It will show your live location on the map if you click tap the map icon at the bottom.

Answer (score 16):

[My Tracks](http://mytracks.appspot.com/) is an app by Google that will record a path you rode with stats.  You can upload your path to Google Maps and stats to Google Docs, or create a gpx/kml file for uploading to other biking, running, or fitness / mapping apps.

Comment: One answer per app please; that way, the best apps can be voted to the top.

Answer (score 13):

A few folks I work with use Strava (http://www.strava.com). There are android and iphone apps, and you can also upload files from Garmin devices. Aside from the standard gps, route tracking stuff, the web site has a social focus. You can follow other riders if you wish. The site also allows you to define road segments and will show leaderboards, king of the mountain badges, and personal bests.

[image]

Comment: Strava has excellent social features and I really like seeing rankings for categorized hills. IMO, the android app for strava is more stable than mapmyride. I evaluated both of them and found strava to be preferable for the app stability and the fact that more riders in my area use Strava (good for tracking progress relative to stronger riders).

Comment: One thing that's annoying with Strava is that even with a premium account the app doesn't let you see segments in real time. I used cliiiimb on my iPhone which had this function, but I can't seem to find an Android equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

I've used [Sports Tracker](http://www.sports-tracker.com/blog/category/android/) a lot on Symbian phones and they now have an Android version coming out (as well as an iPhone version).

[image: Sports Tracker on Android]

It can beep on auto-laps for example every kilometre. You can review your workouts on the phone, something I don't think Endomondo can do. You can use it with a Bluetooth Polar heart rate monitor.

You can see things like this on both the phone and website: route plotted on a scrollable, zoomable map with lap markers (using Open Street Map), duration, distance, average and max speed, energy use, charts of altitude vs. distance, heart rate distribution (light, moderate, hard), heart rate vs. time, speed vs. time and lap timings.

[image: Sports Tracker on Android]

You can upload to their site (which is a bit Flash heavy for my liking) with various permissions (private, visible to friends, visible to everyone), Twitter, Facebook.

Also if you take photos during the workout, it can upload those to the site too, and shows them on the map. You can also edit and export workout routes, and replay them.

[image: Sports Tracker website]

Comment: I use sports tracker with my Symbian phone. Works really great.  Love the charts and graph.  I only with they could substitute (or add) a cadence tracker instead of a heart beat monitor.

Comment: Also wanted to add that Sports Tracker allow you to export the route to many popular formats including KML (Google Earth), GPX, XML, and CSV.

Comment: I'd also add a vote for Sports Tracker. I use it for running, and cycling. Great application and gives you good statistics on times, overall distances, lap times.

Answer (score 6):

[CardioTrainer](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/products.php) is an app that also works with the GPS functionality to track your workouts, and can create tracks and virtual training partners if you do the same routes.

Answer (score 6):

I use [RunKeeper Pro](http://runkeeper.com/); from January it's free for Android; here is the [description](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro&feature=search_result) in Android Market.

It's not only for cycling, but you can choose the activity type to be tracked by GPS, define custom routes and use audio coaching to know your distance, speed, time; then you can see online, in your personal account, a detailed report and a map with your path; if you want, you can also share those details with friends, and create or attend races.
You can also monitor your heart rate, if using along with  [Polar WearLink®+ transmitter with Bluetooth®](http://www.heartratemonitorsusa.com/polar-wearlink-plus-bluetooth.html) for the Android, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Can you please explain what it does?

Comment: Edited my post; hope it's better now :)

Comment: It is indeed, thanks for editing. (We try to stay away from answers that are just links, in case the link breaks in the future.)

Answer (score 3):

[SportsTrackLive](http://www.sportstracklive.com/help/android) is another app listed as supporting the Zephyr heart rate monitor. I haven't tried it; anyone who has, feel free to comment or edit this answer with more information.

Answer (score 3):

[iMapMyRide](http://www.mapmyride.com/imapmy/android/) is great. It records and uploads all your route data to the iMapMyRide web site. Once uploaded you can view the route on a Google map, see the total distance travelled, see a chart of the elevation plus the total gain, add notes, log the workout and share the route with others. I really can't recommend it enough

Answer (score 3):

My app [IpBike](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iforpowell.android.ipbike) Is designed for a phone mouted on the bike, the emphesis on giving you all the information in a clear and consistant way on one basic screen while riding.  Has full support for ANT+ sensors HR, speed, Cadence Speed and Cadance and Power sensors on compatible phones.  Pressure based altitude of compatible phones.  Direct upload for Stava, Runkeeper and Attackpoint.  Can export rides as .gpx, .tcx, .csv, .fit

[image: Main displat with speed cadence and Heart rate.]

[image: Map option with cyceling specific OSM map tiles that can be precached for offline use.]

Comment: Is IpBike your app? If so, please make it clear in your answer.

Comment: The first app in this list (going from highest to lowest rated) that doesn't ask for broad permissions (like permissions for the device id, my contacts list and call data!). A good reason to try this one first

Answer (score 2):

[VeloComputer](http://velocomputer.com/faces/mainpage.jsp?uri=products.jsp) appears to be an attempt at turning a phone into a complete cycling computer. Version 7, which is available for Android, uses GPS for measuring position and speed, and the accelerometer to measure cadence. They also sell Bluetooth enabled wheel and pedal sensors, for more accurate speed and cadence, though those seem to only be supported on Blackberry at the moment.

I have not tried this; it looks interesting, though some of the reviews indicate that it's a bit flaky. Does anyone else have experience with it?

Answer (score 2):

[Run.GPS](http://www.rungps.net/) is mentioned in the list of apps supporting the Zephyr heart rate monitor. I haven't tried it; anyone who has, feel free to comment or edit this answer with more information.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most convenient way of measuring your heart rate while cycling, but [Instant Heart Rate](http://www.instantheartrate.com/android.jsp) is a neat program which might be useful when you to take a break. You use your phone's camera and LED flash (if it has one, otherwise any bright light source) to measure your heart rate by pressing the camera and flash against your finger, and it detects fluctuations in the oxygen content of your blood by detecting changes in color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this free app for measuring your heart rate:

Sports Heart Rate Monitor
see:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.js.hr

you do not need any external hardware and it measures your heart rate quickly. You just need to press it softly against your chest and it will readout your beats per minute.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you want your app to do. However, I use OruxMaps for navigating and tracking. I like it because you can create a local copy of online maps to use where 3G internet connection is not available