# How can I build my own open-source cyclometer?

Tags: diy, bike-computer, open-source

I am interested to build a bike but I would also like to have free software/hardware. How can I build a cyclometer with open-source software? Would it be possible to find reflashable hardware or open schematics?

Comment: @Neil Fein: are you saying that *cyclometer* has nothing to do with bicycles? lol... *start a project*, we live in *it*. We like to have fun with bicycles, why are you so intolerant about fun? I think most of us, repliers and me, won't give a damn to time-limits and such things in so-called *projects*, let us work. If you cannot understand, look there are many other people who understand, read the replies. Very cool!

Comment: Cyclometers are clearly on-topic. This question is simply unclear as it is currently written, and I want to understand it. Stack Exchange, the company that runs these boards, is very clear about what they are to be used for, and that's asking and answering questions. I'm not trying to ruin anybody's fun. However, questions have to be clearly written or at least understandable, and this one, in my opinion, is not yet there. I'm doing my best to help you, not hider you.

Comment: @Neil Fein: *What do you mean?* Yes I am asking here, other people are answering and they clearly understand -- notice there is a clearly-defined understandable question about bicycles which already has many understandable answers. If you are going to remove this question, please, remove also [1], [2] and many other software-hardware related questions. [1] http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/bicycling-apps-for-android [2] http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/725/iphone-4-bike-mount-recommendations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an extremely broad question that's primarily about electronics, rather than cycling. (Rule of thumb test: would it be easier to explain the necessary cycling information to an electronics expert or to explain the necessary electronics to a cyclist? Clearly the former and by a very, very long way.)

Comment: @user652 does this go in the direction you're interested in? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-5V7s0GflU

Comment: I understand this is late, but... if you don't understand a question, please don't change it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its old, and no project was started in the last 12 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest platform is probably [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) - nearest bike thing I can find is [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Bike-Speedometer/)

Comment: +1 cool so I don't need to buy a closed code cyclometer, had actually some arduinos around.

Comment: At the speeds things happen on bicycles it's very easy to just count the inputs from a magnet+switch with an interrupt. Hardest part is probably a suitable cheap display

Comment: Can I slice up the arduino so that it's thumb-sized, weather resistant, and mounts on the handlebars?

Comment: @wdypdx22: I have used this beast [1]. Very small and now planning an automatic chain lubricating thing but unsure of your requirements. Check the specs. [1] http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/

Comment: There are surface mount nano versions http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoNano, or there is this http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLilyPad

Comment: @mgb: cool. Are they on the same non-restrictive license as Arduino? The Teensy is apparently not so these beasts may be better options.

Comment: @hhh all the arduino variants are free and open source, they also use the same very simple IDE and language. You can also get arduino clone boards from local makers, some smaller and cheaper.

Answer (score 5):

The most detailed account/details I've come across for building your own bike computer is here on [PIClist](http://www.piclist.com/techref/piclist/biketut/index.htm).

Those pages contain detailed instructions for building a bike computer using a PIC microcontroller linked to a Hall Effect Sensor (it detects the magnet attached to a spoke as the wheel spins). In addition to the build details it also features a detailed discussion of the design process which the creator undertook whilst creating the computer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to get real time ANT sensor data from a Garmin watch to a PC. But this is difficult. BLE is easier. The following bike computer is very basic, but can be modified by the user:

Pyloton: CircuitPython Cycling Computer. Open Source cycling computer that displays heart rate, speed, cadence, and song playback info.

https://learn.adafruit.com/pyloton